# Background Task using the same data provider as application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, marshalling, background-task

In my solution I have three projects: Application, Class Library providing data and Windows Runtime Component for background task. Problem is, I need bot application and background task to use data provider. And this ends with "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread". Dispatcher isn't quite a solution as I can't retrun something while in dispatcher.

Background Task is called rarely, so is it possible to unmarshall data providing interface for a second so background task could get its data? If it is - how to do that, if it isn't - what else can I do?

Comment: What kind of data are you using ? Is it something in memory or a connection to some external resource (like a DB)

Comment: I'm getting data by JSON from my API. Data providing works just great - problem is when background task needs it, as it is already marshalled for app.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Ensure that calls from the background thread are marshalled to the appropriate thread using a wrapper class. Typically this will mean writing a class that takes the original object as a parameter, replicates its class interface in it's own structure but checks for access before calling the methods directly.
2. Create a new data adaptor that can be called on the background thread.

Either of these options will solve your issue.

Comment: It can be quite problematic. App is localized and I'm using Resources.resw in my data provider. So, using two separate data adapters will get me into marshalled interfaces again.